# Expression when you want to say that you think it is the cause of the error

Tags: grammar

I am an IT engineer.

What expression do you use when you want to say that you think something is the cause of an error?

```
A seems to be making the error.
```

Does this make sense?

Is the cause of the error the subject?

I write [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087027/brew-install-mariadb-fails-as-system-can-not-chown-for-auth-pam-tool/62096238#62096238):

> Unknown variable mysqlx-bind-address seems to be making the error.

Is it correct English?

Comment: Use a pronoun. ***It*** *seems to be making the error.*

Comment: Where should I write it, such as offline, typo?

Comment: A can only make an error if it is a conscious being. If A is a thing, it can do all kinds of things to errors, including producing, generating, triggering, causing, fixing, verifying, reporting, compiling them, or putting them to music. But the one single thing A can never possibly do is *make* an error. (Oh, and nobody and nothing can make *the* error. That's just not English.)

Comment: If **A** is a proper noun, then it's not actually a typo. Perhaps the context is that there are several things, *A*, *B*, and *C*, for example. There is also a single error that's being produced. If so, the example sentence would be grammatical and understandable. But if that's *not* the scenario, are you saying that the **A** in the sentence should be described as a **typo**? Yes, if it was unintentional. But if it was intentional, then it's a **mistake** or just incorrect grammar. I'm not sure what you mean by **offline**.

Comment: After the edit to the question, that sentence is grammatical and understandable. However, it's not very idiomatic. (It's more like what you'd read in a headline.)  It would sound better as the following: ***An*** *unknown **value in the** mysqlx-bind-address seems to be (**responsible for** / **causing**) the error.*